# Creating a new environment once virtualenv has been installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, conda

I have successuly installed `virtualenv` using `pip install virtualenv`. Then i created a new environment under

```
(base) C:\Users\xxxxxx\PythonScripts\TwitterTutorial>
```

using the command `virtualenv myenv`
then as expected a new environment is created under

`C:\Users\xxxx\PythonScripts\TwitterTutorial\myenv`

The next step is to activate this environment using this command

```
(base) C:\Users\xxxx\PythonScripts\TwitterTutorial>.\myenv\Scripts\activate
```

My issue is that the response is as follows:

```
(myenv) (base) C:\Users\XXXXXX\PythonScripts\TwitterTutorial>
```

As you can see, the `myenv` environment is activated on top of the `base` one. I found that weird because i expected a response similar to this

```
(myenv) C:\Users\XXXXXX\PythonScripts\TwitterTutorial>
```

Maybe the command `.\myenv\Scripts\activate` is wrong?

On a different note, i have created environments in the past and to activate them i usually do `conda activate env` and it worked successfully for that particular task (not for this one unfortunately)
Many Thanks for your help

Comment: `(base)` comes from `conda`, `(myenv)` from `virtualenv`. You don't need to use both. If you're already using `conda`, you don't need `virtualenv`, `conda` can be used to create and activate its own virtual environments.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks so much!!!  in that case, i can uninstall virtualenv? i suppose this command should be sufficient 'conda create --name myenv' ?

Comment: Yes to both questions.